# Applescript to Heart or Love or Favorite song

Tags: itunes, applescript

Anyone know if there's away to heart/love/favorite a song in the new iTunes via applescript?  Basically I want the ability to heart a song from Apple Music without switching back to iTunes.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a pretty hacky script that does the job for Apple Music tracks. It right clicks on the app icon in the dock, and selects the first option in the menu.

```
set current_app to current application
activate application "Dock"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Dock"
        set frontmost to true
        activate
        tell list 1
            perform action "AXShowMenu" of UI element "iTunes"
            delay 0.01
            repeat 1 times -- move down one menu item to the 'love' option
                key code 125 -- down arrow
            end repeat
            delay 0.1 -- 0.01 was too fast
            repeat 2 times
                key code 36 -- return key
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
activate current_app
```

(Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819807/accessing-dock-icon-right-click-menu-items-with-applescript))

Again, this is super-hacky, but it works for me when I'm listening via "For You", which is the only time I usually "love" tracks.

Answer (score 5):

This is the script I use. It toggles the loved status of the current track.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if loved of current track is true then
        set loved of current track to false
    else
        set loved of current track to true
    end if
end tell
```

It also works for Apple Music; just replace "iTunes" with "Music".

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it doesn't appear to be possible to get or set properties on music played through Apple Music.

However you can heart a track that is stored locally or played from your iCloud Music Library.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set loved of current track to true
end tell
```

Comment: Yeah thats my problem it works for songs downloaded to your music library.   Apparently a radar has been field http://www.openradar.me/21674162

Comment: Yup. You can see Doug Adams of "Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes" talking about it here too. http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2015/07/itunes-12-2-and-applescript-issues-volume-2/ Hopefully this is something that will appear in a minor update soon.